# How do i change the background color in python of this combined png image?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code that works great except, however it produces a black background image, and i would like it to be white.  I have tried changing bg_color but anything I change it to still keeps the black background.  Is there also a way that i can make a box around each image that i am combining?

```
direction = 'vertical'
bg_color=(1,1,1,1)
aligment='center'

images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['LVISF2_ABoVE2019_0801_R2003_084168.TXT_ZG.png', 'LVISF2_ABoVE2019_0801_R2003_084168.TXT_RH95.png']]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

if direction=='horizontal':
    new_width = sum(widths)
    new_height = max(heights)
else:
    new_width = max(widths)
    new_height = sum(heights)
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (new_width, new_height), color=bg_color)
offset = 0
for im in images:
    if direction=='horizontal':
        y = 0
        if aligment == 'center':
            y = int((new_height - im.size[1])/2)
        elif aligment == 'bottom':
            y = new_height - im.size[1]
        new_im.paste(im, (offset, y))
        offset += im.size[0]
    else:
        x = 0
        if aligment == 'center':
            x = int((new_width - im.size[0])/2)
    elif aligment == 'right':
        x = new_width - im.size[0]
        new_im.paste(im, (x, offset))
        offset += im.size[1]

new_im.save('test4.jpg')
```

Comment: make the `bg_color = (255,255,255,1)`?

Comment: i tried that, and it is still a black background

Comment: And to make matters even more confusiing, the images that i am combining originally have white background, i don't understand why or how the background color is changing

Answer (score -1):

turns out my original png background was not white, it was transparent So i had to change the transparent background to white, and then I was able to change the background color.

Here is how i changed the original png backgrounds to white

```
images1 = ['LVISF2_ABoVE2019_0801_R2003_084168.TXT_ZG.png', 'LVISF2_ABoVE2019_0801_R2003_084168.TXT_RH95.png']

for i in images1:
    im = Image.open(r'{0}'.format(i))
    fill_color = (255,255,255)
    im = im.convert("RGBA")   
    if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
        background = Image.new(im.mode[:-1], im.size, fill_color)
        background.paste(im, im.split()[-1]) # omit transparency
        im = background
    im.convert("RGB").save(r'newimage_{0}.jpg'.format(i))
```